# Bounded linear map bivariate

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

How to show the following:

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be Banach spaces. Let $T(x,y)=z$ be a bilinear map. 
Let $T(x,\cdot)$ and $T(\cdot,y)$ be linear bounded maps on each fixed $x$ and $y$ respectively. 
How to show $T(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a jointly continuous map from $X \times Y \to Z$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try using the fact that $T$ is continuous if and only if it maps bounded sets of $X\times Y$ to bounded sets of $Z$. Maybe it helps

Comment: Why is that statement true Giuseppe? Thank you..

Comment: Try with the Banach-Steinhaus theorem for the family $\lbrace T_x: \|x\|\le 1 \rbrace$ where $T_x(y)=T(x,y)$.

Comment: @SalihUcan: It is because $T$ is continuous if and only if there exists a constant $C$ such that 
$$\lVert T(x,y)\rVert \le C \lVert x\rVert \lVert y\rVert.$$
The qualitative version of this inequality is just the statement made above. *By all means*, I think you'd better listen to Jochen's hint than mine. I have basically told you nothing.